# index for Spatial Data Base with weight parameters

Tags: mysql, database, geospatial

I am in need of a database in which you could create indexes for geographical coordinates and at least one weight parameter ideally several weight parameters.

I know that in MySQL it is possible to create spatial indexes but it will index only coordinates at a time.

In case of large data sets MySQL is not an option as it will create large tables.

So, Is there such a Database available for public?

Comment: Could you please post a sample query against your data?

Comment: Something like ... SELECT *, AsText(loc) FROM data WHERE Contains(
GeomFromText('POLYGON(( poly data ))'),loc ) ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 10;

Answer (score 1):

A spatial index must satisfy the triangle inequality i.e. the graph has to be an euklidian space. I don't think you can put a weight on it nor that there is a database.

Comment: I have a feeling that specific data structure could accomplish this. I am looking for some kind of modification of an R-tree.

Comment: @CoderLatvia: There is spatial index for multi-dimension but that's not for optimizing problems i.e. weights.

Comment: A weight is a relationship so you are looking into edges as in a graph-database.

Comment: @Gustav: How do you want to add the edges to the spatial index? Do you want it to be a third dimension?

Comment: Yeah, that's definite what it is.

Comment: @Gustav: When it's not the 3rd dimension then it's not about geometry?

Comment: @Gustav: Please be specific. I've flag your entire discussion and comment.

Comment: Think of it as the height over sea-level. You can add that relationship in any geographic measurement, like (lat,lng,height). What you got in your "world" is lat, lng and the weight. So when calculating the path across multiple points(nodes) you would indeed do a linear algebra calculation using this weight, (x1,y2,w1)*(x2,y2,w2) etc.

Comment: @Gustav: A spatial index can include more then 2 dimension. I don't understand what you want to express? I already ask you about optimizing and third dimension? What's this all about linear algebra?

Comment: For your purpose you cannot use mysql out of the box. You may use it but you need to model your own relationships.

Comment: I think this is not an easy question, like missing a semicollon in code line. What I am looking for is specific data structure and maybe also working implementation of it. I have a feeling of those answers as : "Hey! Great, post! By the way do you know that 2+2 is 4."

Comment: @CoderLatvia: Gustav told me to use a linear algebra calculation? What does linear means? algebra is a matrix calculation? Is 2+2 a linear algebra?